# How can I concatenate two files in Unix?

Tags: unix

How can I create a new file "`new.txt`" that is a concatenation of "`file1.txt`" and "`file2.txt`" in Unix?

Comment: zcat file1.txt.gz > new.txt for gzip files

Answer (score 96):

```
cat file1.txt file2.txt > new.txt
```

Comment: `cat` actually means _concatenate_.

Comment: Helpful addition: With a ">" the target-file is overwritten with the source-files and with ">>" the source-files are appended to the target-file

Comment: Bash, ksh, zsh: `cat file{1,2}.txt > new.txt`

Answer (score 18):

if the file new.txt is an empty file, you can simply use the cat command :

```
cat file1.txt file2.txt > new.txt
```

if new.txt is not empty, and you want to keep its content as it is, and just want to append the concatenated output of two files into it then use this:

```
cat file1.txt file2.txt >> new.txt
```

Answer (score 6):

If you want to append two or more files to an existing file without overwriting the file's (`file4.txt`) content, then below is an example:

```
cat file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt >> file4.txt
```

Even if the file `file4.txt` is not present, it would get created. If it is present, the other files' contents would get appended to it.